# Outgoing mail runs into a series of spamd errors

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis, clamav

I've got a mail setup using postfix and dovecot, with spamassassin, clamav and amavis. Incoming mail contains the correct X-Spam* headers and everything appears to be operating more or less correct, except for a few erros when sending outgoing mail.

If I compose a message `From: nick@myhost.com` - `To: foobar@example.org` I get some puzzling entries in my mail.log:

```
spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:40516 to port 783, fd 5                                              
spamd: handle_user (getpwnam) unable to find user: 'foobar'                                               
spamd: still running as root: user not specified with -u, not found, or set to root, falling back to nobody 
spamd: processing message <b765df18-dfdd-03a5-b39a-11a608898afd@myhost.com> for foobar:65534
```

I've tried searching for this error (specifically that spamd seems to be looking for a local user by the name of the recipient of the email (but only the sender is a local account on `myhost.com`), with no luck.

At this point I'm not sure which config is relevant to paste here, some documentation says I should be running spamd, others say that clamav or amavis should handle passing the mail through spamassassin and therefore spamd should not be running (however when I stop the daemon, things don't work).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I tried adding -x to spamd, which is supposed to disable per user settings, but this had no effect and I still get the errors you noted.

Comment: @KurtFitzner Unfortunately I don't recall what I did about this issue, eventually I switched to an entirely different mail server setup so this architecture no longer remains.